# How to Change googleusercontent.com as an External Image Blogger

Tags: blogger

So I have tried to used this code for my blogger template to show thumbnail.

```html
<b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage'>
<a class='a-thumbnail' expr:href='data:post.url' itemtype='https://schema.org/ImageObject'>
 <img class='post-thumbnail' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.featuredImage' expr:title='data:post.title' itemprop='thumbnailUrl' />
</a><b:else/>
<a expr:href='data:post.url' itemtype='https://schema.org/ImageObject'>
 <img class='post-thumbnail' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' height='200' itemprop='thumbnailUrl' src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-L_kUUQ1IPIA/XCjxUauyFsI/AAAAAAAAD3U/p64aZgv9GF0qR7O27v7j_QK8eaF9tohnACK4BGAYYCw/s1600/NoImage-min.png' width='336' />
</a>
</b:if>
```

But, why when I use external image and it show **googleusercontent.com** not an original link image?

My external link image :

```
https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Minimal-Phone-Wallpaper-001-1080x2340-945x2048.jpg
```

And it shows like this :

```html
<a class="a-thumbnail" href="https://pinpaper-template.blogspot.com/2020/03/malesuada-bibendum-arcu-vitae-elementum.html" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<img alt="Malesuada Bibendum Arcu Vitae Elementum Curabitur" class="post-thumbnail" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/OtwZzJk06niBX-akp4Ja5GLJNB8ByfiqxXclA8O-OzrWtk9Drg4RSxb_IkaoZwb-dyqF5UqkIp-mMZrthJ1t0ekZ2Rc9P7EYA5OYWbcAw28yuvth6Dk9C6-oabZIcqBZNgDLY4vdIgAvRfG2iD86ZrhEHaulNBJTMsFh" title="Malesuada Bibendum Arcu Vitae Elementum Curabitur">
</a>
```

FYI, in this case I using **b:defaultwidgetversion='2'** and **b:layoutsVersion='3'**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because Blogger uses its proxy to load images from external servers. It is because they want to load images securely over their CDN which also results in faster loading.

Also, Gmail uses similar thing - they load external images in proxy.

There is not much difference in image, only that the url is changed and nothing much.

The URL generated via proxy is temporary and it generates new URL everytime.